# jQuery: check if there are no unchecked radiobuttons in different groups

Tags: jquery, validation, loops, radio-button

I'm doing sort of quiz, that has a lot of `radio button` groups. Like 1 question = 1 radiobutton group with multiple `radio buttons`. User has to check one `radio button` in each group. I decided to give each group of radiobuttons its own class and than use loop to check these groups. For some reason - code doesn't work. Here's the code:

```js
var num = 1;
$("#submit_button").click(function() {
  var alarm = 0;
  $(".input_value" + num).each(function(){
    if(!$(this).is(':checked')) {
      alarm = 1;
    } else {
      num++;
    }
  });

  if(alarm == 1) {
    $("#failure").show(200);
    $("#failure").fadeOut(2500); 
  } else {
    $("#success").show(200);
    $("#success").fadeOut(2500);
  }
});
```

```css
#success {
 display: none;
 margin-top: 50px
}

#failure {
 display: none;
 margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="rate_input">
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value1"  name="q1" value=1>1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value1"  name="q1" value=2>2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value1"  name="q1" value=3>3</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value1"  name="q1" value=4>4</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value1"  name="q1" value=5>5</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value1"  name="q1" value=6>6</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value1"  name="q1" value=7>7</label>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="rate_input">
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value2"  name="q2" value=1>1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value2"  name="q2" value=2>2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value2"  name="q2" value=3>3</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value2"  name="q2" value=4>4</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value2"  name="q2" value=5>5</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value2"  name="q2" value=6>6</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value2"  name="q2" value=7>7</label>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="rate_input">
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value3"  name="q3" value=1>1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value3"  name="q3" value=2>2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value3"  name="q3" value=3>3</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value3"  name="q3" value=4>4</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value3"  name="q3" value=5>5</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value3"  name="q3" value=6>6</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value3"  name="q3" value=7>7</label>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="success">
  <p>Great! Thank you!</p>
</section>

<section id="failure">
  <p>You have to select at least 1 radiobutton in each group!</p>
</section>

<section id="submit">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_button" value="Send!">
</section>
```

`jsFiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/k3Luw4hx/

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an error in your logic. You need to break out of the loop when something is checked. That is, when you find the first "answered" question, you need to break out of that question and continue. However, if you don't ever find an answer to that question -- only then should you set the alarm flag. In your code, it will loop all the matched elements and set the `alarm = 1` if it finds any option that is not checked.

**Edit:**

I made a very inelegant solution to this logical issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/9r7t3rgc/8/ The core of the problem is that you need to loop each question and decide if it has answer or not. The code you provided doesn't do that.

Also, use [.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to check the checked state of the element.

```
$(".input_value" + num).each(function(){   
    if(!$(this).prop('checked')) {
        alarm = 1;
    } else {
        num++;
    }
})
```

Comment: That is the code i was using, except "prop" instead of "is". Not working for me: https://jsfiddle.net/1pycve38/

Comment: Check out the fiddle. You need more code than you have in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is your checking for each and every radio button thats why your code is failing. You should check for classes `.input_value1` `.input_value2` `.input_value3` not each and every button from that class.

```js
var num = 1;

$("#submit_button").click(function() {
  var total_cb = $(".rate_input").length;
  var alarm = 0;

  for(var key=1;key<=total_cb;key++) {
    if (!$('.input_value'+key).is(':checked')) {
      alarm = 1;
    } 
  }
  
  if (alarm == 1) {
    $("#failure").show(200);
    $("#failure").fadeOut(2500);
  } else {
    $("#success").show(200);
    $("#success").fadeOut(2500);
  }
});
```

```css
#success {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 50px
}

#failure {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="rate_input">
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value1"  name="q1" value=1>1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value1"  name="q1" value=2>2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value1"  name="q1" value=3>3</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value1"  name="q1" value=4>4</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value1"  name="q1" value=5>5</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value1"  name="q1" value=6>6</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value1"  name="q1" value=7>7</label>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="rate_input">
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value2"  name="q2" value=1>1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value2"  name="q2" value=2>2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value2"  name="q2" value=3>3</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value2"  name="q2" value=4>4</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value2"  name="q2" value=5>5</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value2"  name="q2" value=6>6</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value2"  name="q2" value=7>7</label>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="rate_input">
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value3"  name="q3" value=1>1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value3"  name="q3" value=2>2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value3"  name="q3" value=3>3</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value3"  name="q3" value=4>4</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value3"  name="q3" value=5>5</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value3"  name="q3" value=6>6</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value3"  name="q3" value=7>7</label>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="success">
  <p>Great! Thank you!</p>
</section>

<section id="failure">
  <p>You have to select at least 1 radiobutton in each group!</p>
</section>

<section id="submit">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_button" value="Send!">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/1pycve38/2/

```js
var num = 1;
$("#submit_button").click(function() {
  var alarm = [];

  $('.rate_input').each(function(i){
    alarm[i] = 0;
    $(this).find("input.input_value").each(function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alarm[i] = 1;
      }
    });
  });
       
  if(alarm.indexOf(0) >= 0) {
    $("#failure").show(200);
    $("#failure").fadeOut(2500); 
  } else {
    $("#success").show(200);
    $("#success").fadeOut(2500);
  }
});
```

```css
#success {
 display: none;
 margin-top: 50px
}


#failure {
 display: none;
 margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="rate_input">
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value1"  name="q1" value=1>1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value1"  name="q1" value=2>2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value1"  name="q1" value=3>3</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value1"  name="q1" value=4>4</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value1"  name="q1" value=5>5</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value1"  name="q1" value=6>6</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value1"  name="q1" value=7>7</label>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="rate_input">
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value2"  name="q2" value=1>1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value2"  name="q2" value=2>2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value2"  name="q2" value=3>3</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value2"  name="q2" value=4>4</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value2"  name="q2" value=5>5</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value2"  name="q2" value=6>6</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value2"  name="q2" value=7>7</label>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="rate_input">
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value3"  name="q3" value=1>1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value3"  name="q3" value=2>2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value3"  name="q3" value=3>3</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value3"  name="q3" value=4>4</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value3"  name="q3" value=5>5</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value3"  name="q3" value=6>6</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="input_value input_value3"  name="q3" value=7>7</label>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="success">
  <p>Great! Thank you!</p>
</section>

<section id="failure">
  <p>You have to select at least 1 radiobutton in each group!</p>
</section>

<section id="submit">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_button" value="Send!">
</section>
```

Looping through `. rate_input` and then loop within the input.

Alarm is an `array`, if answer is checked then value will be 1 else 0.

Hope this will help you.